# How to apply ifelse function by column names?

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply, sapply

I know there are many similar questions around but I'm afraid couldn't get my head around this particular one, though obviously it is very simple!

I am trying to write a simple ifelse function to be applied over a series of columns in a data frame by using **column names** (rather than numbers).  What I try to do is to create a single `u_all` variable as shown below without typing column names repeatedly.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1:20),u1 = sample(c(0:1),20,replace=T) , u2 = sample(c(0:1),20,replace=T) , u3 = sample(c(0:1),20,replace=T)) 
dat<-within(dat,u_all<-ifelse (u1==1 | u2==1 |u3==1,1,0))
dat
```

I tried many variants of `apply` but clearly I'm not on the right track as those grouping functions replicate the `ifelse` function on each column separately.

```
dat2 <- data.frame(id=c(1:20),u1 = sample(c(0:1),20,replace=T) , u2 = sample(c(0:1),20,replace=T) , u3 = sample(c(0:1),20,replace=T)) 

dat2<-cbind(dat2,sapply(dat2[,grepl("^u\\d{1,}",colnames(dat2))],
                               function(x){ u_all<-ifelse(x==1 & !is.na(x),1,0)}))

dat2
```

Comment: When trying to use column names stored in variables, shortcuts like `$`, `with`, `within`, `subset`, etc., are **not** your friend. use `[` exclusively and things work better.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks! But may I ask why? And do you mean, for example, I should avoid using the shortcut, `$`  ( as in `dat$u1` )  and use `dat[,2]` instead?

Comment: `dat$u2` is fine if `"u2"` is the name of a column. But if `u2 <- "mpg"`, `mtcars$u2` will not work because `$` doesn't evaluate `u2`, it looks for a column named `"u2"`. But if `u2 <- "mpg"`, `mtcars[, u2]` **will** work, as will `mtcars[, "mpg"]`. See, e.g., `fortunes::fortune(343)`, `fortunes::fortune(312)` and the warning in `?subset`... which should probably be included in `?with` as well.

Comment: @Gregor I've just seen the `fortunes`. Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line from the OP

> ```
> dat<-within(dat,u_all<-ifelse (u1==1 | u2==1 |u3==1,1,0))
> ```

can instead be written as

```
dat$u_all <- +Reduce("|", dat[, c("u1", "u2", "u3")])
```

How it works, in terms of intermediate objects:

- `D = dat[, c("u1", "u2", "u3")]` uses the names of the columns to subset the data frame.
- `r = Reduce("|", D)` collapses the data by putting `|` between each pair of columns. The result is a logical (TRUE/FALSE) vector.
- To convert `r` to a 0/1 integer vector, you could use `ifelse(r,1L,0L)` or `as.integer(r)` (since TRUE/FALSE converts to 1/0 by default) or just the unary `+`, like `+r`.

If you want to *avoid* using column names (it's really not clear to me from the post), you can construct `D = dat[-1]` to exclude the first column instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for not being clear. I was not trying to avoid column names, on the contrary, I want to _use_ the column names but don't want to type one by one because there are many columns.  So I just edited your code as `dat$u_all <- +Reduce("|", dat[,grepl("^u\\d{1,}",colnames(dat))])` in my script. Works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there, here's a solution using apply over rows and using all to transform a vector of tests to a single digit.

```
dat2$u_all <- apply(dat2[,-1], MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x){ 
  any(x==1)&all(!is.na(x))*1
}
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But  this doesn't seem right. With this code u_all takes the value of 1 only if all three variables (u1,u2, and u3) are 1.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Edited to `any`. Assumed you wanted to test if all values were not missing, unsure how you want those handled.